# Mark / Unmarked another option from a set of enum

Tags: delphi, enums, components

I have a set of `enum` in a `component` like this:

```
type
  TOption = (clVisible, clVisibleAlways, clRenderable, clEditable);
  TOptions = set of TOption;

const 
  defaultOptions = [clVisible, clRenderable];

type
  TMyComp = class(TComponent)
  private
    FOptions: TOptions;
    procedure SetOptions(const Value: TOptions);
  public
    property Options: TOptions read FOptions write SetOptions default defaultOptions;

...

procedure TMyComp.SetOptions(const Value: TOptions);
var
  ToBeSet, ToBeCleared: TOptions;
begin
  if FOptions <> Value then
    begin
      ToBeCleared:= FOptions - Value;
      ToBeSet:= Value - FOptions;

      FOptions:= Value;

      //clVisible -> clRenderable
      if (clVisible in ToBeSet) and (clRenderable in ToBeCleared)  then
        begin
          Include(FOptions, clRenderable);
          Include(ToBeSet, clRenderable);
        end;

      //not clRenderable -> not clVisible
      if (clRenderable in ToBeCleared) and (clVisible in ToBeSet)  then
        begin
          Exclude(FOptions, clVisible);
          Exclude(ToBeSet, clVisible);
        end;

      //not clVisible -> not clVisibleAlways
      if (clVisible in ToBeCleared) and (clVisibleAlways in ToBeSet) then
        begin
          Exclude(FOptions, clVisibleAlways);
          Exclude(ToBeSet, clVisibleAlways);
        end;

      //clVisibleAlways -> clVisible
      if (clVisibleAlways in ToBeSet) and (clVisible in ToBeCleared) then
        begin
          Include(FOptions, clVisible);
          Include(ToBeSet, clVisible);
        end;
  end;
end;
```

What I would like to do and it doesn't work, is to:

- check also `clVisible` if `clVisibleAlways` was checked
- check also `clRenderable` if `clVisible` was checked
- un-check also `clVisible` if `clRenderable` was unchecked
- un-check also `clVisibleAlways` if `clVisible` was unchecked

Please some support about this topic.

Comment: You'll have to take care of that in code, whether you wrap this into a class or record type, or do it inline,

Comment: In other words, there is nothing in the language that lets you do this automatically. The way you do it seems quite right to me.

Comment: Like i indicate, it doesn't work! In the evening i will check again the code.

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Please be more exact. It is not so hard to exclude or include certain other members when a member is set or removed. Personally, I would not make it so hard for myself. if clVisibleAlways is set, then that is a separate option. In your logic that queries those values, you can simply assume clVisible set if clVislbleAlways is set (and likewise for the other values). But I would not set it in the actual set.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think your logic WRT ToBeSet and ToBeCleared makes sense. I would get rid of those. I don't have the time right now, but I will look into this later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is unnecessarily complex.

### Update

One must obviously distinguish between adding or removing an option (which I didn't do before). The updated code does this and works nicely in Delphi 10.1 Berlin. My test component is called `TNewButton` and is based on `TButton`.

```
procedure TNewButton.SetOptions(const Value: TOptions);
var
  Opts: TOptions; { Because of "const"; you can also remove "const" 
                    and use Value instead of Opts. }
begin
  if FOptions <> Value then
  begin
    Opts := Value;
    { Find out if we are adding or removing an option. }
    if Opts - FOptions <> [] then
    begin
      { We are adding an option. }
      if clVisibleAlways in Opts then
        Include(Opts, clVisible);
      if clVisible in Opts then
        Include(Opts, clRenderable)
    end
    else
    begin
      { We are removing an option. }
      if not (clRenderable in Opts) then
        Exclude(Opts, clVisible);
      if not (clVisible in Opts) then
        Exclude(Opts, clVisibleAlways);
    end;
    FOptions := Opts;
  end;
end;
```

I tested it several times, and, at least in my Object Inspector, it does exactly what you wanted.

Comment: in design time, when i checked the `clVisibleAlways`, i should see `clVisible` getting checked, but I didn't. I apply this method with boolean properties and it worked.

Comment: @REALSOFO; ah now I get it. It does not update the object inspector at design time. The options are being set as you wanted, though. They just don't show up in the OI. I'll look into this.

Comment: You might need to have the property setter call the parent Form's `Designer.Modified()` method if `Designer` is not nil.

Comment: No, @Remy, that is not it. When I set clVisibleAlways, then the other two are set too, no need to call Designer.Modified. But I can't *unset* clRenderable, because of the first two clauses. So I must first detect if an option is removed or if one is being added.

Comment: it works now! thank you Rudy! Remy example is also good, but I think still have some chain reaction. Anyhow, thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your `TOption` set into the helper class, which would provide additional logic on assignment:

```
TOption = (clVisible, clVisibleAlways, clRenderable, clEditable);
TOptions = set of TOption;

TOptionHelper = class
public
    constructor Create();
    procedure Include(const AOption : TOption);
    procedure Exclude(const AOption : TOption);
    function GetOptions() : TOptions;
    property Options : TOptions read GetOptions;
strict private
    FOptions : TOptions;
end;

constructor TOptionHelper.Create;
begin
    FOptions := [clVisible, clRenderable];
end;

procedure TOptionHelper.Exclude(const AOption: TOption);
begin

end;

function TOptionHelper.GetOptions: TOptions;
begin
    Result := FOptions;
end;

procedure TOptionHelper.Include(const AOption: TOption);
begin
    case AOption of
        clVisibleAlways :  FOptions := FOptions + [clVisible];
        //and so on...
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use something more like this:

```
procedure TMyComp.SetOptions(const Value: TOptions);
var
  ToBeSet, ToBeCleared, LNewOptions: TOptions;
begin
  ToBeCleared := FOptions - Value;
  ToBeSet := Value - FOptions;
  LNewOptions := FOptions - ToBeCleared + ToBeSet;

  if (clVisibleAlways in LNewOptions) then
    Include(LNewOptions, clVisible);

  if (clVisible in LNewOptions) then
    Include(LNewOptions, clRenderable);

  if not (clRenderable in LNewOptions) then
    Exclude(LNewOptions, clVisible);

  if not (clVisible in LNewOptions) then
    Exclude(LNewOptions, clVisibleAlways);

  if FOptions <> LNewOptions then
  begin
    FOptions := LNewOptions;
    // update the rest of your component as needed...
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is flawed.

The lines

```
  if (clVisible in ToBeSet) and (clRenderable in ToBeCleared)  then
```

and

```
  if (clRenderable in ToBeCleared) and (clVisible in ToBeSet)  then
```

are equivalent - yet this is clearly not what you intend.

I don't think Rudy's solution is quite there either because of the potential contradiction between set and clear.

Here is my suggested solution.

```
procedure TMyComp.SetOptions(const Value: TOptions);
var
  ToBeSet, ToBeCleared: TOptions;
begin
  if FOptions <> Value then
    begin
      ToBeCleared:= FOptions - Value;
      ToBeSet:= Value - FOptions;

      FOptions:= Value;

      //clVisible -> clRenderable
      if (clVisible in ToBeSet)  then
        begin
          Include(FOptions, clRenderable);
          Exclude( ToBeCleared, clRenderable); // avoid contradiction!
        end;

      //not clRenderable -> not clVisible
      if (clRenderable in ToBeCleared)  then
        begin
          Exclude(FOptions, clVisible);
          Exclude(ToBeSet, clVisible);
          Include(ToBeCleared, clVisible ); // Chain reaction - Clearing clRederable clears clVisible and therefore by implication clVisibleAlways!
        end;

      //not clVisible -> not clVisibleAlways
      if (clVisible in ToBeCleared) then
        begin
          Exclude(FOptions, clVisibleAlways);
          Exclude(ToBeSet, clVisibleAlways);
        end;

      //clVisibleAlways -> clVisible
      if (clVisibleAlways in ToBeSet) then
        begin
          Include(FOptions, clVisible);
          Include(ToBeSet, clVisible);
        end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: you are right with the extra lines, but in design-time I see no effect...

Comment: Shouldn't `FNewVal` by `FOptions` instead? In any case, wouldn't it be easier to simply setup `ToBeSet` and `ToBeCleared` as needed, and then use `FOptions := (FOptions - ToBeCleared) + ToBeSet;`?

Comment: Yes, fNewVal should be FOptions, Remy. I was going to do it differently but changed my mind. Have edited source.

Comment: You commented on extra lines REALSOFO, but did you notice all the 'and' statements that have been removed?

Answer (score 0):

I will add the full code I used to solve my question. This will remove some constraints about the order I check or unchecked the options.

```
procedure TMyComp.SetOptions(Value: TOptions);
var
  ToBeSet, ToBeCleared: TOptions;
  clRenderableChanged, clVisibleChanged, clVisibleAlwaysChanged: Boolean;
begin
  if FOptions <> Value then
    begin
      ToBeCleared:= FOptions - Value;
      ToBeSet:= Value - FOptions;

      clRenderableChanged:= (clRenderable in ToBeSet) and (not (clRenderable in FOptions)) or ((clRenderable in ToBeCleared) and (clRenderable in FOptions));
      clVisibleChanged:= (clVisible in ToBeSet) and (not (clVisible in FOptions)) or ((clVisible in ToBeCleared) and (clVisible in FOptions));
      clVisibleAlwaysChanged:= (clVisibleAlways in ToBeSet) and (not (clVisibleAlways in FOptions)) or ((clVisibleAlways in ToBeCleared) and (clVisibleAlways in FOptions));

      FOptions:= Value;

      if clRenderableChanged then
        begin
          if clRenderable in ToBeSet then Include(FOptions, clVisible);
          if clRenderable in ToBeCleared then
            begin
              Exclude(FOptions, clVisible);
              Exclude(FOptions, clVisibleAlways);
            end;
        end;

      if clVisibleChanged then
        begin
          if clVisible in ToBeSet then Include(FOptions, clRenderable);
          if clVisible in ToBeCleared then Exclude(FOptions, clVisibleAlways);
        end;

      if clVisibleAlwaysChanged then
        begin
          if clVisibleAlways in ToBeSet then
            begin
              Include(FOptions, clVisible);
              Include(FOptions, clRenderable);
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Anyhow, this was possible thanks to the help of all persons contribute with answers to this question.

**UPDATE**
I think some of my problems came from the fact I didn't restart Delphi after installing of component changes.